# How can i make the new post listed at top by moving the previous post down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have followed http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and, in that example we can add a new post and it is displayed but the new post is displayed at the bottom when there is a post present already but i wanted to make the new post displayed at the top. How can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post.order("created_at desc") will show the most recently created first.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
@posts = Post.all
```

To

```
@posts = Post.order("created_at DESC")
```

in your `index` method of `app/controllers/posts_controller.rb`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use

```
@posts = Post.order("id desc")
```

ID has primary key (by default). The last post will always have max ID
(Unless you update created_at field)